# Issue printing acronyms over 5 characters using IEEETran class

Tags: ieeetran, acro

I am using the IEEEtran class and I came up with an issue with an acronym.
I can imagine this is caused by the length of the short text of the acronmym but after checking for possible solutions or workarounds I have not been able to find anything.

```
\documentclass[journal, twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %used for header
\pagestyle{fancy} %also used for header
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{IEEE LATIN AMERICA TRANSACTIONS ,~Vol.~7, No.~7, Oct~2020}
\fancyhead[LO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{AUTHOR FIRST NAME  \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: MANUSCRIPT TITLE IN CAPITAL LETTERS}
\fancyhead[RE]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\DeclareAcronym{abcd}{
  short = ABCD ,
  long  = Acronym 1,
}

\DeclareAcronym{abcde}{
  short = ABCDE,
  long  = Acronym 2,
}

\DeclareAcronym{abcdef}{
  short = ABCDEF ,
  long  = Acronym 3,
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\title{IEEE Latin America Transactions Latex Template}

\author{John Doe \orcidicon{0000-0000-0000-0000}\,, \IEEEmembership{Senior Member, IEEE}, % <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Marco~A.~Hernandez-Nochebuena is with LINCE Lab, Instituto Politécnico Nacional Mexico e-mail:email@utfpr.edu.br.}
\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2025; revised August 26, 2025.}}


\markboth{IEEE Latin America Transactions,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2021}{SKM: My IEEE article}  

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Latex template, IEEE, Latin America Transactions, guidelines for authors.
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\ac{abcd}
\ac{abcde}
\ac{abcdef}

\section*{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{References}


\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{}}]{2nd author}
\lipsum[1]
\end{IEEEbiography}

\printacronyms 
\end{document}
```

The problem is I have an acronmym that is 5 characters and when printed it overlaps with the long name, I imagine due to the column width.

[image: Acronyms]

Any ideas on how handle?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `acro` uses a `description` list for the acronym list. And indeed you will see the same with

```
\begin{description}
  \item[ABCD] Acronym 1
  \item[ABCDE] Acronym 2
  \item[ABCDEF] Acronym 3
\end{description}
```

In this case you would use

```
\begin{description}[\IEEEsetlabelwidth{ABCDEF}]
  \item[ABCD] Acronym 1
  \item[ABCDE] Acronym 2
  \item[ABCDEF] Acronym 3
\end{description}
```

in order to tell the list the widest label. To to the same for `acro`'s list you can either

- redefine the `description` template that `acro` uses for the list
- use another template for the list, e.g. `tabular` (this is not doing the same but avoiding the problem in the first place) with `\acsetup{list/template=tabular}`
- use the fact that the `description` template has `\acropreamble` immediatly before `\begin{description}` and smuggle the optional argument to the right place:

```
\newcommand\acrolabelwidth[2]{#1{#2}[\IEEEsetlabelwidth{ABCDEF}]}
\acsetup{list/preamble=\acrolabelwidth}
```

A complete example showing the last option:

```
\documentclass[journal, twoside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{abcd}{
  short = ABCD ,
  long  = Acronym 1,
}

\DeclareAcronym{abcde}{
  short = ABCDE,
  long  = Acronym 2,
}

\DeclareAcronym{abcdef}{
  short = ABCDEF ,
  long  = Acronym 3,
}

\newcommand\acrolabelwidth[2]{#1{#2}[\IEEEsetlabelwidth{ABCDEF}]}
\acsetup{list/preamble=\acrolabelwidth}

\begin{document}

\acuse{abcd,abcde,abcdef}

\printacronyms 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very useful response, thank you!